# How to position the legend inside a fieldset with a border?

Tags: css, forms, legend, fieldset

According to the several references on the web, it is not possible to position a legend. So it is suggested to wrap it with span:

```
<legend><span>Foo</span></legend>
```

Then we can position the span inside the fieldset. but then when I want to add a border on top of the fieldset, there is a gap for the legend. Luckily, I've found that adding border to the legend also fixes this little, tiny gap but that's ugly solution (as everything else with css). Do you have any more valid solutions to this problem?

note: I've found the solution concurrently, after I've started writing this question, so I want to still ask it.

Comment: Let me see if I get this right; You want to know how you can move the legend tag away from it's original position and then close the gap in the top border? If yes, then why even use a fieldset legend tagset?

Comment: You'd do this for semantics and accessibility. The visual styling of an element has little to do with how a machine (e.g. screen reader) treats it.

Comment: This is strange that this cannot be changed, since I thought all default styles in browsers were set through user agent stylesheets.

Comment: Marking this as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652337/prevent-the-fieldset-elements-border-from-going-through-the-legend-element/29652463#29652463) so that people in the future don't have to sieve through all these answers.

Answer (score -13, accepted):

I think this will work

```
 <legend><span>ur text</span></legend>
```

Give border to the legend tag

```
legend {padding: 2px;border: 1px solid green;}
```

Comment: @Craig Wayne Because this answer doesn't solve the problem?

Answer (score 109):

I found that simple `float:left` for `LEGEND` will do the job.

Codepen sample: http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/oFdBa

Comment: Yep, I landed on this page from google, and was surprised `float:left` was so far down the page when clearly the easiest answer.

Comment: This is the best solution. It feels much better than using absolute positioning or any additional elements.

Comment: Yes better than absolute positioning. The legend may have its own height.

Comment: Doen't work in Chrome 55 :(

Comment: nice catch. way better than having to manually account for its unusual implicit height

Comment: This is a whole lot nicer than the other solutions, but it may require paying attention to other elements inside the fieldset. I got around my issue by using padding instead of margin (but that's a pretty particular situation)

Comment: This worked very well. At first my lower elements were appearing to the right of legend, this is fixed by setting the legend width to 100%.

Comment: I found this didn't really work on Safari browsers. You can actually still use a legend element for sake of semantics but utilise `display: contents;` to avoid the wacky placement cross browsers (latest 2 versions of major ones nowadays). Of course this however means you can't add padding, margins etc to the legend element itself.

Answer (score 73):

I know this is an old question, but I got this page when I googled "fieldset legend position", and I really couldn't find a good answer.

The legend just won't behave!, so the best solution I found was to position it absolute and have a padding top on the fieldset. JSFildle example: http://jsfiddle.net/carlosmartinezt/gtNnT/356/

```
fieldset {
    position:relative;
    padding-top:50px;
}

legend {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:18px;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I did not get how relative and absolute worked together until seeing/trying this.

Comment: @Veiko's float should be used. This one is a bad practice as it will fail: http://jsfiddle.net/g18Lwnf7/

Comment: I hate using floats (for anything other than their very specific intended use-case), but in my case I need my legend to sort of flow inline with the rest of the elements in the fieldset, and float was the only thing that worked. I wish `position: static` or `display: inline` worked.

Answer (score 12):

Use an outline instead of a border: http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/gtNnT/

Comment: Outline is useful if you don't care about IE 5/6/7 users (still a good chunk of people). IE 8 and Firefox support (all current versions) are also spotty. If only browser support was better, this would be the best option (so long as you're not trying to do any fance border effects like rounded corners)! http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/outline

Comment: I'm thrilled to report that in 2013, IE5/6/7 user are not a good chunk of people anymore. I think about that and it makes me deeply happy :)

Comment: This does not solve the issue when having colored backgrounds for fieldsets

Comment: ha! uve given presentations at conferences b4 havent u?

Answer (score 10):

The OP almost answered his own question: wrapping does the trick, but it's the other way around. Use:

```
<span><legend>Foo</legend></span>
```

Comment: This is invalid html (at least as of html5).

Answer (score 3):

Set margins for positioning. It works without problems.

```
legend {margin-left:50px;} /* 50px from Left of the Fieldset */
```

Comment: setting a margin-top doesnt work well, as the legend is still offset relative to the fieldset. Its alignment changes as the height of the legend changes

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin-bottom "-50px" for legend and padding-top "50px" for fieldset so do not overlap.

```
fieldset { 
padding-top:50px;
}

fieldset legend { 
margin-bottom:-50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems more straight forward to me.

```
fieldset legend { 
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer on how this solves the issue

Answer (score -4):

Found this the most consistent, tested in IE7, Firefox and Chrome

`fieldset legend 
{
    text-align:left;
}`

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is primarily about vertical positioning, not text alignment.

Answer (score -6):

I ended up using just div elements. In the end, I just need the border and the text over the border, that's it.