# Prevent the fieldset element's border from going through the legend element

Tags: html, css

I have a fieldset, how can I position the legend inside a fieldset with a border? I want the border to go around the legend and not through the middle of it.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79gaLhbd/)

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0!important;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
legend {
  padding: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Title</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for - https://jsfiddle.net/79gaLhbd/3/ Could you provide an image of what you are after?

Comment: An ugly workaround [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79gaLhbd/5/)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking for but you can have the border box in the `fieldset`'s `legend` like so: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79gaLhbd/6/)...

Comment: Or this - https://jsfiddle.net/79gaLhbd/2/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One option would be to float the `legend` element to the left:

```css
fieldset {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
legend {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>This is a legend</legend>
  <label>Here is an input element: <input type="text" /></label>
</fieldset>
```

---

Another approach would be to use an `outline` rather than a `border`:

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
  outline: 2px solid #f00;
}
legend {
  padding: 0.6em 0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>This is a legend</legend>
  <label>Here is an input element: <input type="text" /></label>
</fieldset>
```

---

Another approach would be to absolutely position the `legend` element *relative* to the parent `fieldset` element. This is probably the least flexible approach.

```css
fieldset {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2.6em; /* Displace the absolutely positioned legend */
}
legend {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>This is a legend</legend>
  <label>Here is an input element: <input type="text" /></label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I like the 2nd option, assuming that is the design the OP is after.

Comment: `float: left` doesn't work if the fieldset (parent) is set to `display: flex`

Comment: @BrianFunt None of the examples I posted float the child element of a parent flexbox container. But yeah, your statement is definitely true. The direct children of a flexbox container become flexbox items (which do not behave as a normally positioned element and thus don't respect the `float` property).

Comment: Interestingly it seems to work in IE11. I think the easiest way round this is to put the legend in a span.

Comment: @BrianFunt But that won't validate as valid HTML5 - https://validator.w3.org you will receive the error *"Element legend not allowed as child of element span in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)"*. If you're going to wrap it with a `span` element, you might as well not even use a `legend`. Besides, in terms of semantics that would just feel wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not too troubled by validation, but as you point out, I might as well use a div with class "legend" I suppose?

Comment: An oldie, but I just want to point out that only float-left works if you want to use shadows (on hover for example)

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the accepted answer (using SASS) which should work in all modern browsers (IE9+)

```
fieldset {
  > legend {
    float: left;

    + * {
      clear: both;
    }
  }
}
```

This will clear the next element after the float so you don't have to worry about your layout being messed up.

Comment: Missing a closing brace after `float:left;`

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning that this snippet will not work out of the box in any of the modern browsers, since it is LESS and needs to be preprocessed.

Comment: Have amended comment to mention that it uses SASS and fixed the brace issue.